# Gwt: CellTable CSS removes all other CSS files

Tags: css, file, gwt, celltable, gwt-2.2-celltable

I am having a problem, when I override the CellTable CSS file with mine (a different one), then all other CSS files get disappear and changes the styles etc. on page. 
What could be the problem?

Can I add more styles (other than CellTable's) into celltable CSS file that I override?

Comment: Please explain how you override the css file? (I want to be able to do that in another context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are overriding CSS , are you changing the base style ?

Answer (score 3):

CellTable's styling works differently than most other widgets in GWT. It uses a ClientBUndle to inject its styling information. This bundle is injected last, so it overrides any styling you may have already done.

Look at the CellTable class' code to see how it extends the ClientBundle with its "Resources" interface and how it then extends that with "BasicResources".

To override this default behavior, I had to:
1. create my own css file with different stying
2. create my own interface that extends CellTable.Resource, much the same way that BasicResource does in CellTable.java
3. instantiate my CellTable object with my resource

If you would like, I can email you some source code.